# Conditional Column Selection

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am very new SQL to programming and could use a hand with a project.  I have a table with about 20 columns or so.  I need to evaluate 15 or so of the columns that have numeric properties and return records that do not have a value of zero.  The first 5 column are descriptive text fields that I will always need.  If a column with numeric properities has no records with an amount other than zero I do not want to show the column.  All columns with values other than zero must be shown in the same result.  Thanks in advance for the assist.

Comment: So what have you tried? (so we can estimate your comprehension of SQL Server)

Comment: Not pretty so far.  So I declare tables with a name that match each column name in the original table that I want to evaluate. I insert into the new table the column only if the column in the original table has a value other than 1.  Now I got 20 individual tables or so with one column only that I need to join based on the original unique id of the original table.  I know there has gotta be an easier way to do this.

Comment: Could you give more details about the why instead of about the how? What is your main goal? Btw, you should always be aware of the number of columns your query is returning...

Comment: Ok.  The original table is performing a reconciliation between two other tables and showing net differences in each columns for every record.  I am just concerned about columns that have values that do not have a zero difference because they will require additional action.  So I am trying to skim down the original reconciliation table to show only columns that do not have values other than zero so that I can focus on these problem areas and not have to review a massive report with unnecessary columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be to use an UNPIVOT query to return each one of those numeric fields as a row.  So your results set would look something this:

```
Desc1 Desc2 Desc3 Desc4 Desc5 NumFieldName NumFieldValue
blah1 blah1 blah1 blah1 blah1 Stat1        13
blah1 blah1 blah1 blah1 blah1 Stat2        22
blah1 blah1 blah1 blah1 blah1 Stat3        6
blah2 blah2 blah2 blah2 blah2 Stat1        3
blah2 blah2 blah2 blah2 blah2 Stat2        42
blah2 blah2 blah2 blah2 blah2 Stat3        12
```

You can then filter that result to exclude rows where the NumFieldValue is 0. Here's the documentation for running an UNPIVOT query: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=UNPIVOTData

If you need some help writing that query, post some detail about your table structure and I'll take a look.